# Tensorflow RNN Model Shapes are Incompatible Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a RNN classifier over some text data.

Facts:

- I've been trying to use https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_classification_rnn as an example, however the example uses data downloaded through the tensorflow_dataset package while I have a homegrown data set.
- I feed in a tensor of texts (X) and one-hot encoded arrays (Y).
- I deviated from the example by changing the loss to Categorical Cross Entropy, and I set the final Dense layer to have an activation of softmax and dimension of 32. 32 is the length of each one-hot encoded line. I figured that's what I wanted the final output to be.
- I get an error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 32) are incompatible`

Question:

Why would I get the shape of 1 anywhere in this model? Is there something that I omitted?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    train_encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=len(train_encoder.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim=64,
        mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y_indexes, epochs=50, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: The issue is definitely in the dataset: (None, 32) is the shape of the model output, while (None, 1) is the shape of the provided y_indexes variable. Perhaps you didn't actually one-hot encoded the labels (in which case just do it or use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() as the loss function). If you need more help, please provide the code where you develop your dataset.

Comment: @MassimoZambelli you're dead right. I one-hot encoded it but didn't pass in the correct variable into the fit function. Make your comment an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is definitely in the dataset: (None, 32) is the shape of the model output, while (None, 1) is the shape of the provided y_indexes variable.

Perhaps you didn't actually one-hot encoded the labels, in which case just do it or use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() as the loss function.